# MySQL count by months, years or display 0 if none

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables below. I fetch all different months and years from table *job_statuses* and group them (Done in part 1 of query). Then I would like to go through those results and count all rows in second table *ticket_jobs* if they are in current month&year interval, also for row to be counted, it must contain string "claim" inside *extra_info field*. The question is that I also want results that have no rows done in current time frame. I read that solution to achieve that is to use left join with same table, but I'm not sure if I used it correctly, because they currently still don't show in results.

**Query theory:** get all different months & years from *job_statuses*, cycle through them and count rows in *ticket_jobs* which are in current timeframe of month & years  and have "claim" in *extra_info*. Display 0 if none in current timeframe.

**Table: job_statuses** (data which resources were used and when):

```
id (int, primary ID)
input
created_at (timestamp ex: 2018-06-05 08:00:00)
finished_at (timestamp ex: 2018-06-06 08:00:00)
```

**Table: ticket_jobs** (data about all tickets and which were already claimed)

```
id (int, primary ID)
extra_info (text ex: "claimed:3256262")
created_at (timestamp ex: 2018-06-05 08:00:00)
finished_at (timestamp ex: 2018-06-06 08:00:00)
```

**Current result:**

```
+------+-------+---------+
| year | month | claimed |
+------+-------+---------+
| 2018 | 6     | 120     |
+------+-------+---------+
| 2018 | 7     | 40      |
+------+-------+---------+
| 2018 | 8     | 125     |
+------+-------+---------+
| 2018 | 11    | 46      |
+------+-------+---------+
| 2018 | 12    | 24      |
+------+-------+---------+
| 2019 | 3     | 29      |
+------+-------+---------+
```

**Would like to achieve**

```
+------+-------+---------+
| year | month | claimed |
+------+-------+---------+
| 2018 | 6     | 120     |
+------+-------+---------+
| 2018 | 7     | 40      |
+------+-------+---------+
| 2018 | 8     | 125     |
+------+-------+---------+
| 2018 | 9     | 0       |
+------+-------+---------+
| 2018 | 10    | 0       |
+------+-------+---------+
| 2018 | 11    | 46      |
+------+-------+---------+
| 2018 | 12    | 24      |
+------+-------+---------+
| 2019 | 1     | 0       |
+------+-------+---------+
```

**Current query**

```
SELECT year, month, claimed
    FROM 
    (
        //  Get all months & years from job_statuses table

        (SELECT YEAR(created_at) AS year, MONTH(created_at) AS month FROM job_statuses 
         GROUP BY YEAR(created_at), MONTH(created_at)) x, 

        //  Count rows in ticket_jobs table for each year&month result from above that contains "like", 
        //  or put 0 if count returns empty rows

        (SELECT YEAR(t.created_at) y, MONTH(t.created_at) m, COUNT(*) AS claimed 
        FROM ticket_jobs t
        LEFT JOIN ticket_jobs lj ON t.created_at = lj.created_at AND 
        lj.extra_info LIKE "%claim%" 
        GROUP BY YEAR(t.created_at), MONTH(t.created_at)) b
    )

WHERE year=b.y AND month=b.m 
GROUP BY year, month
ORDER BY year ASC, month ASC
```

**Example**

After execution of first part we get this example data from *job_statuses* table

```
+------+-------+
| year | month |
+------+-------+
| 2018 | 7     |
+------+-------+
| 2018 | 8     |
+------+-------+
| 2018 | 9     |
+------+-------+
```

We have sample data in our *ticket_jobs* table

```
+----+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | extra_info     | created_at          | finished_at         |
+----+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1  | {"claimed":125} | 2018-07-05 06:33:50 | 2018-07-05 06:42:50 |
+----+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2  | {"claimed":86}  | 2018-08-15 06:33:50 | 2018-08-22 06:33:50 |
+----+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 3  |                | 2018-09-01 06:33:50 | 2018-09-03 06:33:50 |
+----+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

**So the result would be**

```
+------+-------+---------+
| year | month | claimed |
+------+-------+---------+
| 2018 | 7     | 1       |
+------+-------+---------+
| 2018 | 8     | 1       |
+------+-------+---------+
| 2018 | 9     | 0       |
+------+-------+---------+
```

Comment: Provide sample table data and expected result that match.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the below part as

```
SELECT YEAR(t.created_at) y, MONTH(t.created_at) m, COUNT(extra_info) AS claimed 
FROM ticket_jobs t
LEFT OUTER JOIN ticket_jobs lj ON t.created_at = lj.created_at AND  lj.extra_info LIKE "%claim%" 
GROUP BY YEAR(t.created_at), MONTH(t.created_at)
```

**Or**

```
SELECT y,m,IFNULL(b.claimed,0) claimed FROM
(
    SELECT YEAR(t.created_at) y, MONTH(t.created_at) m, COUNT(*) AS claimed 
    FROM ticket_jobs t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ticket_jobs lj ON t.created_at = lj.created_at AND lj.extra_info LIKE "%claim%" 
    GROUP BY YEAR(t.created_at), MONTH(t.created_at)
) b
```

Comment: The count works, but I still don't get all rows where 0 should be displayed.

Comment: Can you share the fiddle demo with your sample data